# ng-repeat attribute not working. I am using angularJs but the ng-repeat is not working. Here is my code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-controller

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px" ng-controller="projects_control">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="media-list">
                <li class="media" ng-repeat="project in projects">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#"><img ng-src="{{project.image}}"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{project.name}} <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{project.status}}</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p>{{project.short_description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module("mmproapp",[]);
app.controller=("projects_control", ["$scope", function($scope){
$scope.projects=[{
    image:"Aliens.jpg",
    name:"Quadcopter",
    status:"Currently under work",
    short_description:"This would be a short description about the project that would have atleast 5-6 lines explaining in short about the main goal of the project along with the major difficulty or something like that. Just to fill this description box.",
    long_description:"HCHCKGKJ>LGHCB>KLKYFIUKUJC"
},
{
    image:"daily_tasks.jpg",
    name:"Something",
    status:"Finished",
    short_description:"kmsegadkuyag;klusdglujwecliwe This would be a short description about the project that would have atleast 5-6 lines explaining in short about the main goal of the project along with the major difficulty or something like that. Just to fill this description box.",
    long_description:"HCHCKGKJ>LGHCB>KLKYFIUKUJC"
}];
}]);
</script>
```

I want to use the ng-repeat along with ng-controller to display a lot of projects on my page, in a media format. This is the code i wrote. However, whenever I run it, nothing appears at all in its place. The content (what should have been ideally dispayed) flashes for about half a second before going blank. All i see is a blank page. Kindly tell me where my code is wrong! I have no clue.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Remove the equals sign after `app.controller`. It should be `app.controller("projects_control", ...)`.

Comment: @Lex Thanks a lot for pointing that out. That was a small unidentifiable error for me. Again, thanks a lot. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your application. Please refer to this plunker. It is a full working example from your code. Also there is no ng-app directive

https://plnkr.co/edit/0FZVMoPkMyLUJh4dsRdf?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module("mmproapp", []);

app.controller("projects_control", ["$scope", function($scope) {

      $scope.projects = [{
        image: "Aliens.jpg",
        name: "Quadcopter",
        status: "Currently under work",
        short_description: "This would be a short description about the project that would have atleast 5-6 lines explaining in short about the main goal of the project along with the major difficulty or something like that. Just to fill this description box.",
        long_description: "HCHCKGKJ>LGHCB>KLKYFIUKUJC"
      }, {
        image: "daily_tasks.jpg",
        name: "Something",
        status: "Finished",
        short_description: "kmsegadkuyag;klusdglujwecliwe This would be a short description about the project that would have atleast 5-6 lines explaining in short about the main goal of the project along with the major difficulty or something like that. Just to fill this description box.",
        long_description: "HCHCKGKJ>LGHCB>KLKYFIUKUJC"
      }];

    }]);
```